# angular, ng-class with function inside repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to put a class on an input if it meets certain requirements and am having problems

it looks like so -

```
 ng-class="'isPartial': canPartial($index)"
```

This is inside a repeat, the function it's referring to looks like so

```
$scope.canPartial = function(index) {
     var needsMet = _.reduce($scope.allAccounts[index].schools, function (memo, schools) {
  return memo + (schools.selected ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
     console.log(needsMet);
return (needsMet === $scope.allAccounts[index].schools.length);
};
```

so it's using underscore.js to check if all its children are checked. I know the function works correct, however my issue is passing it as the condition for the ng-class. So if it returns true it will add the class. I'm getting a $parse.syntax error and I cannot seem to figuire out why because I se other examples of ng-class using a function. Perhaps it's because I'm trying to pass the $index, however it is inside a repeat, but I don't know if that causes an issue.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-class` [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) is invalid.
Change your [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) declaration in order to take an object as a value:

`ng-class="{'isPartial': canPartial($index)}"`